# RegistryKey, c# не видит некоторые ключи

Tags: c#, реестр

Здравствуйте, есть проблема с доступом к ключу, который создан через  * *.reg* файл. Все ключи, что можно просмотреть через *regedit*, метод **GetSubKeyNames()** возвращает, исключением из правила является мой.

Внимание, вопрос: "как сделать так, чтобы метод **GetSubKeyNames()** вернул экземпляр **RegistryKey**?".

Привожу последовательность выполненных действий:

1. Создание ключа в реестре

> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{1176EC70-36AD-48B8-8B3B-4D5FB64A4639}]
>   @="MyProgID"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{1176EC70-36AD-48B8-8B3B-4D5FB64A4639}\InprocServer32]
>   @="C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\SomeFolder\Some.dll"

Сохранил, переименовал из * *.txt* в  * *.reg*

2. Запускаю файл на выполнение

(Открываю консоль)

> cd /Users/UserName/Desktop/SomeFolder
>
> thisFile.reg

3. Проверка

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ключ и его значение присутствуют в реестре. Отлично!

4. Получаю список имен хранящихся в данной ветви реестра

   `var rk = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey("CLSID");`

   `rk.OpenSubKey("{1176EC70-36AD-48B8-8B3B-4D5FB64A4639}"); //вернет null`

   `//правильность введенного имени ключа можете не проверять, если что :)`

В результате метод *OpenSubKey(**string** str)* выбросил null, намекнув, что данного ключа нет, хотя, как было показано ранее, он есть!

ЗЫ: Права доступа, открытие ключа для записи и установка прав через метод *SetAccessControl(**RegistrySecurity** rs)* не помогают. 
Есть предположение, что создание реестрового файла было выполнено не правильно. 
Очень надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Comment: А другие ключи в CLSID открывает?

Comment: Вы знаете, только что перепроверил и открываются не все ключи в CLSID, некоторые - да,  некоторые - нет. С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: Кажется, это опять 32-64 bit redirector... Попробуйте собрать свое приложение как 64-битное и снова проверьте

Comment: Вы оказались абсолютно правы, это помогло! Не могли бы вы в ответе объяснить данную  особенность ОС Виндовс?